# How to filter a jagged array by using the where function

Tags: c#

I have a jagged array that looks like this:

```
string[][] list = new string[d.Rows.Count + 1][];

int c = 0;
        while (c < d.Rows.Count)
        {
            list[c] = new string[] 
                {
                  d.Rows[c].ItemArray[2].ToString(),
                  d.Rows[c].ItemArray[1].ToString(),
                  d.Rows[c].ItemArray[4].ToString(),
                  d.Rows[c].ItemArray[5].ToString(),
                  d.Rows[c].ItemArray[7].ToString(),
                  d.Rows[c].ItemArray[3].ToString(),
                  d.Rows[c].ItemArray[14].ToString()
                };

            c += 1;
        }
        return list;
```

Now, for a new requirement, i need only the items from this array whose value at this location:  list[x][0] are equal to any of the following strings: "Text", "FullText", "FullMatch"

I got started with a regular array i could do this: but it obvioulsy won't work for a jagged array.

```
string[][] newlist = list.where(item => item.equals("Text");
```

Does any one know how to extend this for my situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a where on `list` which will iterate over each one-dimensional array, then compare element `0` to the strings given.

```
string[][] newlist = list
    .Where(item => item[0].Equals("Text") 
        || item[0].Equals("FullText") 
        || item[0].Equals("FullMatch"))
    .ToArray();
```

Tested this on some sample data as shown below:

```
        var list = new string[][]
            {
                new string[] { "Text", "A", "B", "C", "D" }, 
                new string[] { "None", "Z", "C" },
                new string[] { "FullText", "1", "2", "3" }, 
                new string[] { "FullMatch", "0", "A", "C", "Z" },
                new string[] { "Ooops", "Nothing", "Here" },
            };

        string[][] newlist = list.Where(item => item[0].Equals("Text") 
            || item[0].Equals("FullText") 
            || item[0].Equals("FullMatch")).ToArray();

        // now display all data...
        foreach (string[] row in newlist)
        {
            Console.Write("Row: ");

            foreach (string item in row)
            {
                Console.Write(item + " ");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

This worked correctly with output being:

```
Row: Text A B C D
Row: FullText 1 2 3
Row: FullMatch 0 A C Z
```

Comment: this is definitley on teh right track but i am not getting any data, i get Object not set to an instance...

Comment: @iwant_B_smrtr: Can you give some sample data in your question?  That way I can test it.  Right now I can only test on what I assume the data will be.

Comment: @iwant_B_smrtr: Just tested with data.  I'm betting there might be something in the way your array is being built from the dataset.  Can you catch the exception and see what line it refers to?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted a fully LINQ-based solution, then I think the following should do the trick (although I haven't tested it, because I'm not usre what the variable `d` refers to):

```
var res = 
   (from c in Enumerable.Range(0, d.Rows.Count) 
    let list = new string[] { 
        d.Rows[c].ItemArray[2].ToString(), 
        d.Rows[c].ItemArray[1].ToString(), 
        d.Rows[c].ItemArray[4].ToString(), 
        d.Rows[c].ItemArray[5].ToString(), 
        d.Rows[c].ItemArray[7].ToString(), 
        d.Rows[c].ItemArray[3].ToString(), 
        d.Rows[c].ItemArray[14].ToString() 
      }
    where list[0] == "Text" || list[0] == "FullText" || list[0] == "FullMatch"
    select list).ToArray();
```

A jagged array is just an array of arrays, so you can process it using LINQ. The only trick is that individual items will be arrays (representing your columns). After using `Where`, you can turn the result back to an array using `ToArray`:

```
string[][] newlist = list.Where(item => item[0] == "Text" || ... ).ToArray();
```

Comment: unfortunately, i cannot use linq for this project

Comment: @iwant_B_smrtr: If you can't use linq, why are you using a `where` clause in your example?  I guess I'm confused...  Or do you mean you can't use the LINQ query syntax?